# Solving PDE implicitly or explicitly depending on stiffness

Tags: pde, implicit-methods, explicit-methods

I've got a system of several PDEs for a multitude of parts which represent real hydraulic parts like pipes or thermal energy storages. Each of these parts may have an arbitrary number of nodes and/or or dimensions.
The PDEs of most parts are non-stiff, while a few parts tend to have quite stiff PDEs.
Thus filling one sparse matrix with all of these parts and solving this matrix using one and the same solver, like embedded RK(4)5/Dormand-Prince or embedded Heun methods is not easily feasible.

Currently I solve the PDEs of each part for itself. For this example let's say using an embedded Heun method with adaptive stepsize control. Therefore each part has a function (in the simulation program) which returns its derivative for the given set of variables. This derivative is then
used to calculate the intermediate steps of the Heun method for each part separately. Values shared between parts, like temperatures of contact areas, are updated in between stages AND steps. This results in the following programm control flow with the stepsize $h$:

1. Determine predictor step input variables for all parts
2. Predictor step:

   1. Get derivative of part 1 and calculate the intermediate result of it with $y_{interm,i+1} = y_i + h*deriv_{pred}(y_i)$
   2. Do the same for part 2
   3. ... until part n.
3. Update value array which stores the variables of contact areas
4. Corrector step:

   1. Get derivative of part 1 and calculate the final step result of it with $y_{i+1} = y_i + h/2*(deriv_{pred}(y_i) + deriv_{corr}(y_{interm,i+1}))$
   2. ... until part n.
5. Check if von Neumann stability was violated and if yes, reduce the stepsize $h$, reset value array for connection variables and go back to 2.
6. Get error estimate and if error too big, reduce stepsize $h$, reset value array for connection variables and go back to 2.

This approach works really well for most parts. But as soon as there is only one stiff part out of 1000 non-stiff-parts, the stepsize $h$ may easily be reduced to about $1/100$ of the "old" stepsize.
To deal with this, I thought that solving only the stiff parts with an implicit scheme may be a good approach, since there will be several hundred parts of which only 2 or three will be stiff. This would retain the fast calculation speed of the non-stiff parts as well as the "big" stepsize, at the cost of a higher computational cost for the stiff parts and an increased truncation error in these parts.
The new control flow would be:

1. Determine predictor step input variables for all parts
2. Predictor step:

   1. Get derivative of part 1 and calculate the intermediate result of it with $y_{interm,i+1} = y_i + h*deriv_{pred}(y_i)$
   2. Do the same for part 2
   3. ... until part n.
3. Get implicit PDE solution for stiff parts with half stepsize with $y_{imp,i+0.5} = y_i + h/2*deriv(y_{imp,i+0.5})$
4. Update value array which stores the variables of contact areas
5. Corrector step:

   1. Get derivative of part 1 and calculate the final step result of it with $y_{i+1} = y_i + h/2*(deriv_{pred}(y_i) + deriv_{corr}(y_{interm,i+1}))$
   2. ... until part n.
6. Check if von Neumann stability was violated and if yes, reduce the stepsize $h$, reset value array for connection variables and go back to 2.
7. Get error estimate and if error too big, reduce stepsize $h$, reset value array for connection variables and go back to 2.
8. Get final implicit PDE solution for stiff parts with half stepsize with $y_{imp,i+1} = y_{imp,i+0.5} + h/2*deriv(y_{imp,i+1})$

In this example I used Euler implicit method, but I'd preferably integrate something like Crank-Nicolson.

---

Will this be ok from a numerical/mathematical point of view? Is this a good idea? Or is there any other way to do it? Any concerns?
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What you're trying to do would normally be called an implicit-explicit (IMEX) solver, for when the ODE has the form $\dot y=f_{\text{non-stiff}}+f_{\text{stiff}}$? (Also makes this question easier to search for.) Is there a specific reason you are implementing all this yourself instead of using an off-the-shelf library?

Comment: Thanks for that hint, I'll look into IMEX solvers. Well, the reason for implementing this by myself is that I have so many different parts, all with different numbers of nodes and/or dimensions, that I did not find any solver which could handle this. Besides that the derivatives of my parts have exactly the same shape as the value arrays of my parts. For most parts this means 1D or 2D with the x/y-length the same as the x/y node numbers. Reshaping this to a tri-/penta-/octa-diagonal matrix seemed to be more effort to me, than writing my own solver. Or is there any solver which can solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just slap together an implicit and an explicit method you will likely have order loss. You can do so with low order methods though, and [Crank-Nicholson mixed with some other integrator is an easy way to get a decent second order integrator](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Evshankar/5620/IMEX.pdf). Higher order IMEX integrators like [the Kennedy and Carpenter Additive Runge-Kutta methods](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168927402001381) or the [SBDF schemes](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f3de/1e6ddc008fab31abd206761ca57bfa4f057c.pdf) are specifically designed to solve $u' = f_{stiff} + f_{nonstiff}$ at higher order (with adaptivity and all of that jazz). These are the kinds of methods you're looking for if you want efficiency.

There are two open source implementations that I know of. The [Sundials ARKODE](https://computation.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/arkode) library and the [DifferentialEquations.jl Split ODE Solvers](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/solvers/split_ode_solve.html#OrdinaryDiffEq.jl-1) both have these same higher order additive Runge-Kutta methods, and DifferentialEquations.jl also has the lower order ones plus the SBDF methods in development. I would recommend the DifferentialEquations.jl ones not just because I am the lead developer of the JuliaDiffEq organization (disclosure), but also because the ARKODE implementations tend to diverge without coefficient tweaks on any heavily stiff equation according to the benchmarks (for example, here's [a test on OREGO](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqBenchmarks.jl/blob/master/StiffODE/Orego.ipynb), and there's [a lot more tests here](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqBenchmarks.jl). These same tweaks are shown in the [ARKODE C++ example code](https://computation.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/download/arkode-2.1.1.tar.gz) in order to make ROBER not diverge, so even the developers know), so while it's a part of Sundials it's not as robust as the more well-known CVODE integrator.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! Unluckily I wont be able to take a look into the links and solver packages before monday. I'll respond as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer Chris. I'll try to sum up my thoughts as short as possible. The julia package looks great and I'd really like to use it, but I am restrained to python. Besides that my PDEs are shaped in a way, which is, looking at the tutorial examples (not fully understanding all parts of julia, thus I might be wrong), not supported by the package. For each part in my simulation environment, I have a value array, the temperature, which is shaped $M\times N\times K$, where $M$ is the the number of nodes in $x$-direction, $N$ the number of nodes in $y$-direction etc...

Comment: Each part has a `diff`-function, which returns the differentials of the part for a given set of input parameters, most importantly the temperature at the nodes and the massflow in the nodes. These differentials have exactly the same shape $M \times N \times K$ as the value arrays. The coefficients of the PDEs, like the diffusivity, are temperature and massflow dependent and partially also dependent on the grid position. This is approximated by empirical relations like Nusselt equations, since simulating these parameters with CFD or others is impracticable.

Comment: In the simulation environment I have several 100 parts of different shapes and number of dimensions (most are 1D, thus having vectors as arrays, some are 2D and 3D). Adding these to a matrix of linear equations would be a tremendous effort, especially since the empirical equations for things like the diffusivity would need to be updated in each step. Furthermore having only one 3D part in a system of 1000 1D parts would require the solver to solve a septa-diagonal matrix for all parts. **So is there any feasible way to pass a system of `diff`-functions which share the boundaries to a solver?**

Comment: Furthermore each part is added by a user who in most cases does not know much about numerical computations. **And things like PID controllers interact with the parts in between the timesteps to control for example massflows or internal heat productions.** This, in combination with the empirical relations, will make it really hard to discretize the PDEs for each part so that a low error is maintained. Huge jump discontinuities will occur in between timesteps. Multi-step-methods are thus not feasible.

Comment: The errors introduced by this (the accuracy of the empirical relations is at around 5%), at least this is what I thought, a few magnitudes higher than the error introduced by "just slapping together" an implicit and an explicit method. **Is that so? Or will the error of mixing implicit and explicit methods be *really huge*?** (I don't know any other way to quantify this, sorry. :) )

Comment: To give you an understanding of the timescales which are being simulated: A timeframe of 1 week is what I currently aim for. The explicit embedded RK4(5) method results, for a relative AND absolute tolerance of $tol_{rel} = tol_{abs} = 1e-3$, in timesteps of around $\Delta t \approx 1s$. The stiff parts reduce the timesteps to around $\Delta t_{stiff} \approx 0.025s$. Von Neumann stability breaches would occur at the stiff parts at around $\Delta t_{vN,stiff} \approx 0.4s$. This results in ca. $600e3$ steps for a non-stiff simulation and ca. $24e6$ steps with stiff parts.

Comment: This is of course not feasible. Comparable system simulation tools thus often reduce the timestep to ca. $\Delta t \approx 300s = 5min$ for simulations over a week by smoothing and resampling input time series and using implicit solvers. **So their errors should be several orders of magnitude higher than just slapping together an implicit algorithm for stiff parts with an explicit alogorithm for the other parts. Is that so or is there any additional error or problem which I will introduce by just mixing the solvers?** Sorry for that lengthy comment and thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a lot of separate discrete questions that need a new thread. The 3D by 1D question I have no idea. Mixing implicit and explicit: it's not huge. You get order loss and some stability loss but at 1e-3 you're not using high order effectively anyways. Generally if you mix solvers you can introduce error and without a proof the method is only Order 1, though from some of the sources I sent you can see that getting to Order 2 isn't difficult and sometimes can happen automatically. Order 3+ requires real work.

Comment: Yes, I'll open new threads for the other questions as soons as I have reached a point where it is crucial to my progress. Ok, thanks. So my current explicit order is 2 and if I mix it with an implicit method of order 2, the resulting order will still be 2, right?

Comment: "So my current explicit order is 2 and if I mix it with an implicit method of order 2, the resulting order will still be 2, right?" That doesn't necessarily hold. A priori it's only order 1, but what I am saying is that there are cases where it comes out to be order 2 but without a proof you can't be sure.

Comment: Ok, thanks alot Chris. I'll do some research on publications considering this topic (I'll start with what you posted) and see what I can do.